# Should I repeat other answers to form a complete one?

Tags: discussion, answers

If a question has multiple solutions and someone has already provided one solution. Should I include that solution in my answer in an attempt to create one complete answer? Or is it better to just present the other possible solution?

Comment: If you're suggesting the same solution but a bit better (e.g., more concise code), you should credit the answer you're improving (and include content from it as necessary to be a complete answer).  If you're suggesting a new approach to the problem, don't feel compelled to make the first half of your answer a rehash of the other one.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this has been discussed somewhere, possibly now residing on Meta.SE.